# magento2 checkout page incomplete rendered

Tags: magento2

When i checkout a product in cart, my checkout page renders incomplete as shown with the system log which says :

```
[2016-07-25 10:35:13] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_39779d713e3fbb1543956771d12cf7164 and handles default, checkout_index_index: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:13] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3177627f91af678a9b03e993f1a91917f and handles checkout: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header-wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'top.container' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'footer' element cannot be added as child to 'footer-container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header.container' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and '' respectively. [] []
[2016-07-25 10:35:14] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

[image]

My browsers console says:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using a different install of magento 2. This would bring up an error. I don't know if this will affect anything else but if you go to vendor\magento\framework\Locale (depending on how you have installed magento) and open Format.php, at line 112 is:

```
$defaultSet = $localeData['NumberElements']['default'] ?: self::$defaultNumberSet;
```

Change this to:

```
$defaultSet = self::$defaultNumberSet;
```

Comment: Could you please tell what do you mean by different install of magento2 cause it was working for me for the same instance before which i get all of a sudden ! And why do we have to change the $defaultSet ?

Comment: I have installed Magento by cloning the  git hub repository  and have also tried installing magento via composer. In both installations the cart and the checkout would not load. For some reason the contents of the $localData is not being populated but is still returning true so the self::$defaultNumberSet was not being used. You shouldn't have to make the above change but that is the only solution I could come up with after trawling through the internet to find a solution and reason why it wasn't working.

Comment: I dont think its the right way to modify magento's core files...

Comment: I agree and wouldn't normally touch the core but for what ever reason this seems to be an issue. Note that I am using WAMP so it may be something to do with that. How have you installed magento 2 and which platform is it installed on and platform details (wamp, server, php apache).

Comment: thru github repo 2.2.0 ver xampp php apache...